# help in configuration of mysql 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, configuration, installation

i am trying to install mysql 5.5 in my windows 7 32bit 
i have antivirus quickheal with a firewall 
my problem is i am not able to configure the mysql properly

this all error which i am facing 
[image]

[image]

[image]

can anyone help me out with this issue please

Answer (score 0):

The first screenshot said that the installer must have been run with administrative privileges.

Please logon as administrator and turn off your firewall, then reinstall mysql.

Comment: i am loggedon using admin privileges

Comment: right click on the exe -> run as administrator